# How to pass extra variables and parameters to jQote2?

Tags: variables, parameters, jqote

I have a couple Javascript functions which concatenates a URL which I set to the variable **c**.  I then try to pass that variable into jQote2:

```
$.get("emptyReq.tpl", function(tmpl,c) {
  $("#reqs").jqoteapp(tmpl, result, c);
});
```

In emptyReq.tmpl, I'm doing the following:

```
<tr id="row">
  <td name="id" class="id"><a href="<%=this.c%>"><%= this.FormattedID %></a></td>
  <td name="name" class="name"><%= this._refObjectName %></td>
  <td name="state" class="state"><%= this.ScheduleState %></td>
  <td name="owner" class="owner"></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried a couple of variations (this.c and c) and I've also tried different variables, but I'm not able to get the URL to display correctly.

**c** is labeled as undefined in the console, and the URL ends up being something like: http://127.0.0.1/xampp/py2/undefined instead of the actual **c** which is something like https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/rally.sp#/2735190513d/detail/userstory/4599269614

Is there a way to pass the parameters properly?  Or am I supposed to do the concatenation in the .tmpl file itself?

Here is what I've been using as a reference: [jQote Reference](http://aefxx.com/api/jqote2-reference/).

Answer (score 0):

rishimaharaj,

the `jqoteapp` method's third paramter is used to change the template tag (`<% ... %>` by default) on a per call basis. If you need to pass additional data to your template you have two options:

1. Make `c` a global variable (I wouldn't recommend that, though)
2. Copy `c`'s value to the `data` parameter (recommended):

   Please be aware that the copying needs to take into account of what type your
   templating data is, i.e. a single object is handled different from an array of
   objects!

   ```
   $.get("emptyReq.tpl", function(tmpl,c) {
       var data;

       // 'result' seems to be a global var, thus making a copy is a good idea.
       // Copying needs to take into account the type of 'result'

       if ( Object.prototype.toString(result) === '[object Array]' ) {
           data = result.slice(0);
       } else {
           data = [$.extend({}, result)];
       }

       // Now it is safe to add 'c' to the wrapping array. This way
       // we won't override any homonymous property
       data.c = c;

       // Call the processing with our local copy
       $("#reqs").jqoteapp(tmpl, data);
   });
   ```

   Once you've changed this, you will be able to access `c` through the templating
   lamda's inherent property `data`:

   ```
   <tr id="row">
       ... <a href="<%= data.c %>"><%= this.FormattedID ...
   </tr>
   ```

Regards,
aefxx